# Generate all source hbm and java files using hibernate tools for eclipse

Tags: java, hibernate, code-generation

I'm a little confused. The tutorials and answers I have seen have you creating the hbm files. What's the point of that? I want to setup my mysql connection to my db and say *generate* and *poof* all the nesacary files must be there properties files hbm files java source code the works. Is tat possible or am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it is better to write hbm files on your own. cause the "generate and poof" way is not 100% full proof. Also if your domain object naming is not proper, it might create wrong column name . 
Plus you misses the hibernate various properties suitable for your requirements. 
Eg: You may want to use sequence as id generator but hbm defaults it to increment .

btw, why not look for **annotation**.

**EDIT**

You have to install hibernate tools. 
http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.1.0.Beta1/hibernatetools/html/plugins.html
Above is the step by step guide

Comment: My domain is quite simple actually. So is there a "generate and poof" way at least as a start. I can always modify the hbm files later

Comment: yes you can then .but make sure you take a glance at the generated hbm.

Comment: Sure. My question is still *how*. I cant for the life of me figure out this tool.